# How can I find out about right-of-way or easements when purchasing Land with powerlines?

Tags: real-estate

I found a nice piece of land that I wish to purchase.  I've never purchased a house or land before and I'm hoping for some advice.

The property has quite a bit of acreage, but it appears that on the southern edge of the property, there are high voltage power lines cutting through the property occupying and cutting off apx. 10% of the property with a 100ft wide swath of powerlines approximately 800+ feet long.  Pretty sure these are very high voltage as well and there's 4 or 5 towers on the property.

I'm guessing the electric company has some sort of right-of-way (hopefully non-permanent).  Aside from asking the realtor, is there a way I can find out what kind of agreement exists?  Don't power companies normally pay money for this or deduct from your power bill? The powerlines are depicted on the southern (bottom) most portion of the property image.

[image: Property Image]

Comment: Can you add the country tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is extremely likely there is a utility easement (or right for utilities to use your property) and it will almost certainly be permanent. Also, assuming you are in the USA, it is very unlikely you are going to get any form of remuneration for their use of your land, especially if the easement already exists when you purchase it.

Most likely the appraisal district will have an online map of the property showing the easements. I suggest doing a Google search on "Your county name" Appraisal district. Many of them have an online search feature that you can look for an address and see a non-official version of the plat map which includes things like approximations of easements.